# Is there a command for setting unbuffered stdout and stderr in Windows batch?

Tags: shell, batch, batch-file

I want to setup a command with unbuffered stdout and stderr.
In Unix system, it can be achieved by using **stdbuf -o0**.
For Python scripts, it can be achieved by using **python -u**.
What is the equivalent command in Windows batch?

Comment: `import sys;` then e.g. `sys.stdout.flush()` where needed?

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have a generalized unbuffered mode. It will only work this way
for console (terminal) output.

The post
[What is the equivalent of unbuffer program on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516258/what-is-the-equivalent-of-unbuffer-program-on-windows)
has a working solution in
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44531837/165358).

The solution uses the open-source Github project of
[winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty),
using switches documented in
[Document the undocumented -X switches #103](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty/issues/103).

Winpty is described as below. It was written for a slightly different use,
but it can provide the desired result.

> winpty is a Windows software package providing an interface similar to a Unix pty-master for communicating with Windows console programs.

Use it as follows:

```
winpty.exe -Xallow-non-tty -Xplain your_program.exe | receive_unbuffered_output.exe
```

Where the switches are:

- `-Xallow-non-tty` - allow piped output
- `-Xplain` - remove added Linux terminal escape codes.

(Note: I haven't ever used Winpty.)